# Link Excel spreadsheet into PowerPoint presentation

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I need to create a weekly PowerPoint presentation for various levels of management, to keep them apprised of the status for several categories of action items my department tracks. During normal operations, most of these action items are tracked via several Excel spreadsheets. There's a separate spreadsheet for each action item category.

(Yes, I know we should be using a different application, and storing this sort of stuff in a database, instead of spreadsheets. That's in work, but I still need an interim fix for this while we're stuck with Excel.)

The spreadsheets used to track the action items are very detailed, but the presentation needs to be kept brief, so we usually omit some of the specifics from the presentation. Below are some example fields which are commonly found in the tracking spreadsheets. Items in bold are the only fields we want to show in the presentation.

- **ID**
- **Title**
- Description
- **Status**
- **Progress Notes**
- **Current Responsible Party**
- **Affected Customer**
- Start Date
- **Due Date**
- Project Milestone(s) & Milestone Date(s)
- Document Reference(s)

Currently, the process to create the presentation entails manually going through the Excel spreadsheets and copying/pasting the data into tables created on the PowerPoint slides. However, it would be much more preferable if we could get this process automated to some degree. Also, in addition to keeping these slides up to date for each week's presentation, I need a method to save a static snapshot on a monthly basis for archiving purposes.

What I need is a way to link the spreadsheets into the presentation slides. Ideally, the solution should be able to:

- Pull only the columns needed from each sheet.
- Pull only non-completed action items from each sheet.
- Refresh data from the source sheets, either automatically or on-demand, with minimal user action required.

  - (i.e.: An on-demand refresh should only take a few clicks per sheet - or, more preferably, just a few clicks for the whole presentation - and not require a lot of repetitive copy/paste/etc.)
- Automatically add/remove slides when needed, to accommodate the size of the data sets.
- Permit saving a static copy of the presentation on-demand.
- Be compatible with both Office 2010 and Office 2013.

Is there a way to link my spreadsheets to the presentation, which can serve all these needs?

Comment: IIRC, there's an ability to link Office documents all the way back to Office 2003. About the rest of the functionality I am more amiss, but I would assume that it would be possible to occult specific columns.

Comment: Use a pivot table to get the data exactly the way you want and then use that information and automate it over to PowerPoint.

Comment: Have you tried to "Paste Special" the Excel data into the PPT presentation using "Paste Link"?

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to [download and install](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=39379) the standard (and free) Microsoft product "Power Query", you can. More information about the use of Power Query can be found [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/combine-data-from-multiple-data-sources-HA103993145.aspx). It is available from Office 2010 and up. It provides you with a lot of tools to select and merge data from different sources.

In your case, do the following:

- Create a new Excel workbook.
- Using Power Query, load the first action list to your Excel sheet .
- Use "Append" to append the other action lists to the resulting table. At the end, you should have a (dynamically linked) combined list of all your action lists.
- Using Power Query you can delete and rearrange the columns, sort the data and set filters on the columns. I recommend that you do the selection, sorting and filtering here in the Power Query, because if you do this in the final table in Excel, you need to re-apply all those filters every time you update the table.
- Save the workbook and close Excel.
- Start Powerpoint and on the Insert tab on the Ribbon choose Object and select "Create from file" and select the newly created Excel workbook with the combined action lists.

If you need to update the data, open the Powerpoint presentation and open the Excel object en click on the Refresh button and your data is updated. That's just a few clicks to update *all* of the action lists (cool, right?!)

This solution works for Office 2010 and 2013.

Finally there are your requirements about spanning multiple sheets and saving a static copy. There is no out-of-the-box answer to that, but I'd like you to consider to do this:

- Keep a "master" version of your Powerpoint with the reference to the Excel file in it (*hint: make this file read-only*).
- Every week, update the data with a few clicks as described above.
- Copy the Excel table (even if it is too big for one sheet) and paste it *as a picture* (Paste - Picture or Paste - Paste special... - Microsoft Office Graphic Object).
- Now you can duplicate the entire PowerPoint slide with the picture on it and use the cropping tools (select the picture and choose on the Ribbon tab Picture - Format - Crop) to select the right items on each sheet.
- You can reduce the size of the PowerPoint presentation by selecting a picture and go to the Ribbon: Picture - Compress Pictures and choosing the appropriate settings.
- Finally the sheet with the original Excel data can be deleted from this week's version of the presentation.

It is not really automated, but it keeps a non-editable version of your data in the presentation and it fulfills all of your requirements. The advantage of this approach is that all of the work can be done from the Powerpoint presentation itself.

Comment: How will the presentation/sheet behave on systems without Power Query?

Comment: Not sure. The Excel sheet will show up, but refreshing the data isn't possible I think, because Power Query is needed for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps to your request and I can't answer all of them in detail but I can help you with a few pieces. It'll still be mostly concept, though. I'm a VBA junky so that what I'm going to suggest. It would be significantly easier if you can get access to PowerPoint 2003 because they removed the macro recorder starting in 2007. If you can't do that, then there will be some trial/error/Googling to get it done. Thankfully, a lot of the structure carries over from Excel but not the unique items.

Background) I do something similar to this in my current job. I have a giant mass o' data and I extract pieces of a record if it meets certain criteria and create a PowerPoint slide that contains those details. For my purpose, each record gets its own slide but it seems that you want a slide with a table showing lots of records.

Concept) VBA loops through each data sheet, checks each record to see if it's needed, pulls out certain information from that record, and adds it to a table object in PowerPoint.

1) Pull only the columns needed from each sheet
Easiest to maintain in the VBA code if your data is in a table but manageable without it. You have to explicitly code which cells to extract so just code the ones you need.

2) Pull only non-completed action items from each sheet
Write checks into the code that pulls the status and, if it doesn't equal "Closed" or whatever term you use, then continue with adding it to the slides. Otherwise, skip it and move to the next record. My needs are so complex that I made several helper columns to figure out if a record should be included or not and the VBA just checks that.

3) Refresh data from the source sheets, either automatically or on-demand, with minimal user action required
VBA in PowerPoint can open Excel and call a macro within that file so you can make a button on the slide to run the update macro in Excel.

4) Automatically add/remove slides when needed, to accommodate the size of the data sets
I would start off by removing the old slides and only adding them as needed. You could do something in the code that checks the size of the table object vs the size of the slide and, once it's gets too big, add a slide and create a new table object to start working on.

5) Be compatible with both Office 2010 and Office 2013
I can't promise anything here but most things in VBA are backwards-compatible. I have seen old macros break because some reference was removed or something, but it's only happened once and it was a messy beast of a project.

6) Saving a static copy of the presentation manually
Since every copy is a static copy, independent from the original Excel sheet, this is as easy as File > Save As

7) Saving a static copy automatically
I can't tell if you want to save the Excel or PowerPoint automatically but this would work for both. I use a standard module I've written to make backups of files I'm developing so I can always refer to a previous version. Mine is written to create a backup whenever the file is opened. It only runs once per day or once per second, depending on how I call it. You could modify it to run a max of once per month by just changing the date format in the file name.

```
Option Explicit

Function BackupThisFile(Optional AddTimestamp As Boolean = False)

    'Declarations
    Dim fPath As String
    Dim fName As String
    Dim fExt As String
    Dim iExt As Integer
    Const backupFolder As String = "Backups"

    'Get file path
    fPath = ThisWorkbook.path
    If Right(fPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then fPath = fPath & Application.PathSeparator

    'Add the backup folder name
    fPath = fPath & backupFolder
    If Right(fPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then fPath = fPath & Application.PathSeparator

    'Create the backup directory if it doesn't already exist
    On Error Resume Next
        MkDir fPath
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Get file name
    fName = ThisWorkbook.Name                   'Get file name with extension
    iExt = InStrRev(fName, ".")                 'Find the . separating name from extension
    fExt = Right(fName, Len(fName) - iExt + 1)  'Saves the extension
    fName = Left(fName, iExt - 1)               'Clips the extension

    'Compile path, file name, date stamp, and extension into one variable
    fPath = fPath & fName & " " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    'Add timestamp if required
    If AddTimestamp Then fPath = fPath & " " & Format(Now, "hhmmss")

    'Add the file extension
    fPath = fPath & fExt

    'Save a copy if it doesn't already exist
    Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fso.fileExists(fPath) Then ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fPath

End Function
```