# Code iterating slowly

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a simple macro that gets creates 16 different versions of a template, updating by getting values from another open workbook. It is taking over a minute to iterate only 16 times and was wondering if there was a way I could speed this up? It will become an issue because I eventually need it to iterate 64+ times.

I have a feeling the reason my code is slow is because I access worksheets too often in my loops. I have also looked into possibly reducing the number of string comparisons but that didn't seem to make much of a difference.

Thanks

```
Sub getORSA()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook, template As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim scenario As Variant, scenario2 As Variant, division As Variant, analysis As Variant
Dim a As Variant, b As Variant, c As Variant, confirm As Variant
Dim iterations As Integer
Dim templatePath As String, path As String, name As String, extension As String
Dim result As String
Dim timeOn As Date, timeOff As Date

'check the user wants to run script
confirm = MsgBox("Run ORSA script?", vbYesNo)
If confirm = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If

timeOn = Now

'initialise variables & objects
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("T.change")
scenario = Array("Base") ' while testing use just one scenario
scenario2 = Array("Base", "Base (2)", "Inflation", "Deflation")
division = Array("LGAS SHF", "LGPL SHF", "SRC", "FINANCE")
analysis = Array("GROUP EC", "GROUP SII", "LGAS EC", "LGAS SII")

'template variables and open template
templatePath = "\\..."
path = "\\..."
name = "ORSA_"
extension = ".xlsx"
Set template = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=templatePath)

iterations = 0

    For Each a In scenario
        For Each b In division
            For Each c In analysis

                'update values on template
                With template.Worksheets("EB")

                    ' --SET HEADERS ON TEMPLATE -- '

                    .Range("C2").value = Trim(Right(c, 3))
                    .Range("G2").value = a
                    .Range("C4").value = "LGC"

                    Select Case b
                        Case "LGAS SHF", "SRC"
                            .Range("E4").value = "LGAS"
                        Case "LGPL SHF"
                            .Range("E4").value = "LGPL"
                        Case "FINANCE"
                            .Range("E4").value = "FIN PLC"
                     End Select

                    .Range("G4").value = "LGC"

                    Select Case b
                        Case "LGAS SHF", "LGPL SHF"
                            .Range("I4").value = "SHF"
                        Case "SRC"
                            .Range("I4").value = "SRC"
                        Case "FINANCE"
                            .Range("I4").value = "FIN_PLC"
                    End Select

                    ' -- SET VALUES ON TEMPLATE -- '

                    'update dropdowns of T.change tab
                    ws.Range("B1").value = a
                    ws.Range("B2").value = b
                    ws.Range("B3").value = c

                    Dim investmentReturn As Range
                    Dim capitalTransfer As Range
                    Dim cashSurplus As Range
                    Dim ifrsProfit As Range
                    Dim assets As Range

                    Set investmentReturn = ws.Range("C62:I62")
                    Set capitalTransfer = ws.Range("C64:I64")
                    Set cashSurplus = ws.Range("C65:I65")
                    Set ifrsProfit = ws.Range("C66:I66")
                    Set assets = ws.Range("C67:I72")

                    .Range("D17:J17").value = investmentReturn.value
                    .Range("D30:J30").value = capitalTransfer.value
                    .Range("D34:J34").value = cashSurplus.value
                    .Range("D46:J46").value = ifrsProfit.value
                    .Range("D52:J57").value = assets.value

                End With

                'save and close the template file
                template.SaveAs _
                Filename:=path & name & a & " - " & b & " - " & c & extension, _
                FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

                iterations = iterations + 1
            Next c
        Next b
    Next a

template.Close

timeOff = Now - timeOn

MsgBox ("Successfully ran " & iterations & " iterations" & vbNewLine _
    & "Time: " & Format(timeOff, "hh:mm:ss"))

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

For clarity, this snippet is essential, as it changes values on my master sheet to the values that need to be entered into each version of the template:

```
'update dropdowns of T.change tab
ws.Range("B1").value = a
ws.Range("B2").value = b
ws.Range("B3").value = c
```

Thanks

Comment: I was looking into that, I found the `SELECT` more readable. I swapped them for `IF` and didn't particularly see an improvement in speed

Comment: Fair enough. Besides turning off calculations, I can't think of anything here, except maybe use less variables and more hard-coded, if the variables are using system resources. Maybe look at [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038350/when-should-an-excel-vba-variable-be-killed-or-set-to-nothing) to see if that affects you.

Comment: Thanks @Raystafarian, I turned off automatic calculation and used calculate in the only place I needed it and it's now 3x faster. Good suggestion! Now I'm wondering where else it was calculating, as I only expected one calculation

Comment: Maybe off topic, but there are specialist solutions for ORSA reporting (such as for example [this one](http://www.secondfloor.com/eframe-for-solvencyii-orsa-reports).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this before the code begins

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

and use this before the sub ends

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Without seeing the rest of your code, I don't quite understand why you are assigning values to hard coded ranges after the loops begin. They would change every loop.. or are you looping through workbooks/sheets?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can add the rest of the code if you think it would help, I have used Application.ScreenUpdating = False, but not manual calculation since I need calculation on (in theory). I have one ws that has changing values based on three dropdowns. I need to update those dropdowns each iteration, then use the new values on that ws to populate each instance of the template. Let me know if you still want the rest of the code

Comment: @CallumDS33 can you turn off calculation at the beginning of the run and then re-enable it before saving? Yes, posting the entire subroutine would make it easier to refactor.

Comment: I've added the rest. If I turned calculation off I would presumably need a `calculate` after `ws.Range("B3").value = c` so that the values on my lookup ws update, as I use the updated values lower down at `Set investmentReturn = ...`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to skip VBA and try to solve it with Microsoft Power Query, just as I explained in [the answer for this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/804541/link-excel-spreadsheet-into-powerpoint-presentation) about merging Excel tables.